# Rebuild a jenkins job programmatically

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

We have a three layer multi configuration which at times fails since some sub job fails at times on some slaves
We are looking at rebuilding the whole job across all slaves selected in parent job from the beginning if any of the sub jobs fail
I have looked at rebuild plugin, but am also looking at a programmatic way of solving the problem, any guidance would help

Answer (score 0):

Try Jenkins Remote Access API. This can do it.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

Comment: While this will allow you to resubmit a job with the same parameters, this isn't the same as clicking the "rebuild" button.